# oracle sql dynamic query to select column in cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I've declared the below cursor and variables:

```
l_level           VARCHAR2(100);
l_level_value     VARCHAR2(100);
l_select_clause   CLOB;
CURSOR l_data IS
    SELECT LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3 
     FROM  LEVELS;
```

Then I loop through the cursor:

```
FOR c1line IN l_data
LOOP
    CASE WHEN c1line.LEVEL1 IS NULL THEN l_level := 'c1line.LEVEL2'
         WHEN c1line.LEVEL2 IS NULL THEN l_level := 'c1line.LEVEL3'
         WHEN c1line.LEVEL3 IS NULL THEN l_level := 'c1line.LEVEL4'
         ELSE l_level := NULL
    END CASE;
END LOOP;

l_select_clause := 'SELECT ' || l_level || ' INTO l_level_value FROM dual;';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_select_clause;
```

And then I have some other statements that execute depending on what is selected into the variable `l_level_value`

My problem is that when execute my procedure I get the following error:

ORA-00904: "C1LINE"."LEVEL2": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "MY_PROCEDURE", line 110
ORA-06512: at line 2

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What line is it failing on? Is `C1LINE` declared as `l_data%rowtype`? I don't think your CASE WHEN is right -- it will set l_level to NULL whenever c1lin1.level1 is **not** NULL.  I think it should be: `l_level := coalesce(c1line.level1,c1line.level2,c1line.level3,c1line.level4)`.

Answer (score 1):

About the Actual Error `c1line.LEVEL1` , you open the cursor dynamically? it seems valid in thee code you have shown

Then..

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` Accepts bind variable, whereas INTO should be after Execution only. To mention, Semicolon (`;`) is not needed in the Query String

```
l_select_clause := 'SELECT ' || l_level || '  FROM dual';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_select_clause INTO l_level_value;
```

Comment: the value inside `l_level` matters.. `ORA-00904: "C1LINE"."LEVEL2"` shows, you pack the String `C1LINE.LEVEL2` inside l_level? Where-as your code shows, you just assign the value from C1LINE.LEVEL2. You missed/modified some part while posting.

Comment: Sorry, you are completely correct.  I've edited the original post.

Comment: Now, as you would have guessed, 'c1line.LEVEL2' is not a valid column until you have a table(alias) C1LINE1 with a column LEVEl2. As you query from Dual obviously it ends in error.

Answer (score 0):

My Question is, do you really need dynamic script? I mean same operation can be performed as

```
FOR c1line IN l_data
LOOP
    CASE WHEN c1line.LEVEL1 IS NULL THEN l_level_value := c1line.LEVEL2
         WHEN c1line.LEVEL2 IS NULL THEN l_level_value := c1line.LEVEL3
         WHEN c1line.LEVEL3 IS NULL THEN l_level_value := c1line.LEVEL4
         ELSE l_level_value := NULL
    END CASE;
END LOOP;
```

Why taking two steps? First assign the value to l_level and then assign same value to l_level_value? That too using dynamic scripts?

**Always remember, dynamic script should be the last and last options. You should avoid it.**

Comment: Well, dynamic SQL can make your code **much** smaller. But you are right, in many cases it is simply not neede.

Comment: Yes, dynamic SQL *can* make code smaller. But it also can throw nasty errors as you have experienced.